# custom text metabox in page-admin won't save

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, meta-boxes

I added a custom-meta-box for pasting a slider-shortcode to my page-admin... I am trying to get my custom meta box saved for hours now. But for somehow it is not working. I could swear that my code is correct, but probably it is not... Can anyone help me out please? That would be a great favour! Thank you!

```
<?php
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'cd_meta_box_add' );
function cd_meta_box_add()
{
add_meta_box( 'my-meta-box-masterslider', 'Masterslider Shortcode', 'cd_meta_box_masterslider', 'page', 'normal', 'high' );
}

function cd_meta_box_masterslider()
{
// $post is already set, and contains an object: the WordPress post
global $post;
$values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
$text = isset( $values​['my_meta_box_masterslider'] ) ? $values['my_meta_box_masterslider'] [0] ) :''; 

// We'll use this nonce field later on when saving.
wp_nonce_field( 'my_meta_box_nonce', 'meta_box_nonce' );
?>

<p>
    Falls ein individueller Slider auf der Seite platziert werden soll, bitte hier den Shortcode platzieren.<br />
</p> 
<p>
    <label for="my_meta_box_masterslider">Masterslider Shortcode</label>
    <input name="my_meta_box_masterslider" type="text" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($object->ID, "my_meta_box_masterslider", true); ?>">
</p>

<?php    
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'cd_meta_box_save' );
function cd_meta_box_save( $post_id )
{
// Bail if we're doing an auto save
if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

// if our nonce isn't there, or we can't verify it, bail
if( !isset( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'my_meta_box_nonce' ) ) return;

// if our current user can't edit this post, bail
if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) return;

// now we can actually save the data
$allowed = array( 
    'a' => array( // on allow a tags
        'href' => array() // and those anchors can only have href attribute
    )
);

if( isset( $_POST['my_meta_box_masterslider'] ) )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_meta_box_masterslider', esc_attr( $_POST['my_meta_box_masterslider'], $allowed ) );

}

?>
```

Comment: $text = isset( $values​['my_meta_box_masterslider'] ) ? $values['my_meta_box_masterslider'] [0] ) :'';  has a stray ) just after [0] which will break the code

Comment: And <?php echo get_post_meta($object->ID, "my_meta_box_masterslider", true); ?> will throw an error as $object is not defined - that whole block should be <?php echo $text; ?> as well

Comment: Thank you @SimonPollard . I changed that. Unfortunately, my meta-box still stays empty after saving. There might by anything else we did not see... These are the two lines I changed: `$text = isset( $values​['my_meta_box_masterslider'] ) ? $values['my_meta_box_masterslider'] [0] :''; ` and `<input name="my_meta_box_masterslider" type="text" value="<?php echo $text; ?>">`

Comment: Something very odd going on with the $text = line as well - I can see its not working so I rewrote it and its fine... copy and paste this over your existing line: $text = isset($values['my_meta_box_masterslider']) ? $values['my_meta_box_masterslider'][0] : null; and make sure your input box is updated to use $text as per above

Comment: @SimonPollard thank you so much! Works perfectly. What exactly did you mean by using $text as per above? Just want to make sure not to miss something out ;-)

Comment: great stuff - and I just meant that your input value should be $text - I will write up a full answer to clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cd_meta_box_masterslider function has a few issues:

- There is a stray ) in your $text = line
- The value you have for the input wont work as its referencing something that does not exist
- Finally something odd is going on with the $text = line - I rewrote it and it now seems ok

Full updated code for you to use...

```
function cd_meta_box_masterslider()
{
// $post is already set, and contains an object: the WordPress post
global $post;
$values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
$text = isset($values['my_meta_box_masterslider']) ? $values['my_meta_box_masterslider'][0] : null;

// We'll use this nonce field later on when saving.
wp_nonce_field( 'my_meta_box_nonce', 'meta_box_nonce' );
?>

<p>
    Falls ein individueller Slider auf der Seite platziert werden soll, bitte hier den Shortcode platzieren.<br />
</p> 
<p>
    <label for="my_meta_box_masterslider">Masterslider Shortcode</label>
    <input name="my_meta_box_masterslider" type="text" value="<?php echo $text; ?>">
</p>

<?php    
}
```